# How to see SQL objects from Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I created a database project in VS2010, created the connection to my SQL Server 2008 R2 database and I know it's connected because I can write a SQL command and it works. It even auto-suggests table names as I type.

I want to be able to use SSMS-style things like browse table names & stored procedures, right-click on them and do the tasks.

But I'm not even able to see the tables. I have both Solution Explorer and Schema View on the right side and it shows the whole tree, but not a single table under `Schemas >> dbo >> tables`.

Here's the schema view

[image]

And here is the server explorer view after adding the server.

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you right, Use server explorer you can find it in VIEW tap OR Click

```
 Ctrl + Alt + S
```

And connect to your server and database it will show every thing on that database